# Application of Monads

Tags: haskell, types, monads, boolean-logic

The code below provides for testing the satisfiability of a 2-SAT boolean formula (a formula containing just clauses of the form X v Y). Although other algorithms exist (strongly connected components of the associated implication graph, literal assignment through SLUR) this program does so by applying resolution recursively until an empty clause, i.e. an implied contradiction is found. I have commented the code to explain how it works (just in case)

Even though the code compiles/works, I can't help but feeling that it feels a bit 'hacky' and could be made more Haskell-like by using Monads.

```
-- Literals are numbered and are identified by their integer number X; -X represents a negated integer 
-- A 2-CNF clause X v Y  is represented by a tuple of a 2 integers (X,Y)  
-- 0 represents a empty space (i.e. a non existing literal). So (X,0) or (0,X) is a unit clause and (0,0) represents an empty clause

isEmptyClause :: (Int,Int) -> Bool
isEmptyClause c = (fst c == 0) && (snd c == 0) -- c denotes a clause. (0,0) is an empty clause

isUnitClause :: (Int,Int) -> Bool
isUnitClause c = not (c `isEmptyClause`) && (fst c ==0 || snd c == 0 || uncurry (==) c ) -- c denotes a clause. A unit clause has one literal. Three cases : (X,0)=(0,X)=(X,X)

isTautological :: (Int,Int) -> Bool
isTautological c = not (c `isEmptyClause`) && (fst c == - snd c) -- c denotes a clause. (X,-X) is a tautological clause as it is always true, thus meaningless

isSamePair :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> Bool
isSamePair p p' = fst p == fst p' && snd p==snd p' || fst p==snd p' && snd p==fst p' -- p and p' denote a pair of integers, each in a tuple. NB : 2 cases (X,Y)=(X,Y)=(Y,X)

isIdentical :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> Bool
isIdentical c d = c' `isSamePair` d' -- c and d denote clauses to be compared.
                where c' = checkHiddenUnitClause c ; d' = checkHiddenUnitClause d -- making sure that (X,X) => (X,0) for clauses c and d 

containsClause :: [(Int,Int)]-> (Int,Int) -> Bool
containsClause s c = any (isIdentical c) s -- s denotes a set of clauses and c denotes an individual clause

derivedClause :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -- derived through resolution
derivedClause c c' -- c and c' denote clauses to be potentially resolved. resolution : AvB,-BvC => AvC. Four possible cases
    | fst c /=0 && fst c == - fst c' = (snd c,snd c') -- (X,Y), (-X,Z) => (Y,Z)
    | fst c /=0 &&fst c == - snd c' = (snd c,fst c') -- (X,Y), (Z,-X) => (Y,Z)
    | snd c /=0 && snd c == - fst c' = (fst c,snd c') -- (Y,X), (-X,Z) => (Y,Z)
    | snd c /=0 && snd c == - snd c' = (fst c,fst c') -- (Y,X), (Z,-X) => (Y,Z)
    | otherwise = (1,-1) -- this results in a tautological clause, and is thus harmless/meaningless. will be filtered out

derivedClauses :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)] -- takes a clause and see if there are any resulting derived clauses by applying resolution to a set of clauses
derivedClauses c s = filter (not.isTautological) s' -- Any derivation that results in a tautological clause is filtered out of the derived set
                    where s' = map (derivedClause c) s -- c is a clause and s being a set of existing resulting clauses. the result s' is a derived set of clauses (from applying resolution)

-- Potentially a clause in the original clause set or any subsequently derived clause can be of the form (X,X), however because X v X => X : (X,X) => (X,0). 
-- getting clauses to the form (X,0) or (0,X) is essential if we ever want to find the empty clause (0,0) through resolution. Thus the clause may need to be rewritten as (X,0)
checkHiddenUnitClause :: (Int,Int)-> (Int,Int)
checkHiddenUnitClause c -- c denotes a clause.  
    | not (c `isUnitClause`) = c -- returns just the clause c if it is not a unit clause
    | fst c == 0 = c -- returns (0,X) if the unit clause is of the form (0,X)
    | otherwise = (fst c, 0) -- returns the unit clause in the form (X,0)

-- The following function expands the set of clauses by finding derived clauses (through resolution)
-- This recursive function does so by establishing a stack of existing clauses and a set of of resulting clauses
-- By "popping" the stack, clauses are assessed one by one and matched up against each of the resulting clauses for a possible derivation of a new clause (through resolution) 
-- The newly derived clauses are placed on the clause stack
-- The "popped" clause is added to the set of resulting clauses
-- the recursion terminates and unwinds, when the clause stack is emptied or when an empty clause is found in the clause stack (in which case the function results in an empty set)
expandClauseSet :: ([(Int,Int)],[(Int,Int)]) -> ([(Int,Int)], [(Int,Int)]) -- establishes a clause stack and a seperate set of resulting clauses
expandClauseSet ([],s) = ([], s) -- s is the set of resulting clauses. If the end of the clause stack is reached, the function returns the set of resulting clauses
expandClauseSet (c:cs,s) -- cs is the clause stack and c is the clause popped off the clause stack. s is the set of resulting clauses
    | (c `isEmptyClause`) = ([],[]) -- if an empty clause is found, return an empty clause stack and an empty set of resulting clauses
    | (c `isTautological`) || (s `containsClause` c') = expandClauseSet (cs, s) -- ignore the popped clause if it is tautological or already exists in the set of resulting clauses
    | otherwise = expandClauseSet (cs ++ derivedClauses c' s, c':s) -- add derived clauses to to the claus stack and add the popped clause to the set of resulting clauses
    where c' = checkHiddenUnitClause c -- this is to verify that the popped clauses is not actually a hidden unit clause. if so, modify it to a regular unit clause c'

expandedClauseSet :: [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
expandedClauseSet [] = []
expandedClauseSet s = snd (expandClauseSet (s,[])) -- s denotes a set of clauses

isSatisfiable :: [(Int,Int)] -> Bool
isSatisfiable s = expandedClauseSet s /= [] -- s denotes a set of clauses to be checked for satifiability
```

I can potentially see three areas where this is the case and were Monads coud be used:

1. The `derivedClause` function returns a tautological clause if there is no resolution to be applied; this seems a bit of a hack. It would probably be better to return Nothing instead. Does this mean I should rewrite all instances of an `(Int,Int)` tuple in terms of a `Maybe` monad or should this be a Monoid (still struggling with monads tbh)?
2. Each clause is represented by an `(Int,Int)`tuple of representing the two literals in the clause. That is fine, but maybe it would be nice to have my own definition (maybe I would like some other definition of a literal rather than `Int`).  I am trying to get a declaration of my own type, like:

   ```
   data Clause = Clause {literal ::Int, otherLiteral :: Int)
   ```

   This should in work in principle, right? However, in refactoring the rest of the code I get a lot of type errors. Maybe I am just missing something. Is this worth pursuing, or is it more clear the way it is? Also, I guess this is related to the previous point, wouldn't it be nicer if the non-existing literal or empty space could be represented by `Nothing` rather than the number 0)?
3. The way the `expandClauseSet` recursive function works with its stack and resulting list looks to me also very much like a `State` monad (with the resulting list being the state). Am I right in thinking this or is this taking monads too far?

Answer (score 3):

I would start with (2): your data representation does not seem to do a very good job of representing the data you describe in the problem statement. You always have exactly two integers, even when you really mean just one or none at all. As a result, you have to do a bunch of checking everywhere for how many of the integers you should actually pay attention to. And you have this special relationship between positive and negative numbers, which is not reflected in the types.

Instead, as often in Haskell, start with a `data` definition for each domain object, with constructors for each separate "case" you want to model. One straightforward way to model this domain would be

```
data Variable = Variable Int deriving Eq

data Literal = LitTrue Variable
             | LitFalse Variable
   deriving Eq

data Clause = Contradiction
            | Tautology
            | Unit Literal
            | Disjunction Literal Literal

data Formula = Conjunction [Clause]
```

Really, I would do more, like parameterize the `Literal` type instead of fixing it to `Int`, but this is already a big improvement. Many of the functions that you wrote don't even need to exist anymore: pattern matching does it already.

But of course you still need functions somewhere to do logic, like to say that a clause of "`x0` ∨ ¬`x0`" results in a tautology. That function might look like:

```
negateLit :: Literal -> Literal
negateLit (LitTrue x) = LitFalse x
negateLit (LitFalse x) = LitTrue x

clause :: Literal -> Literal -> Clause
clause x y | x == y = Unit x
           | x == negateLit y = Tautology
           | otherwise = Disjunction x y
```

`derivedClause` is a function that still needs to exist, and touches the low-level representation, so I thought I would show how it would look with the new representation. You need a couple extra clauses to address the fact that unit clauses are no longer disguised as 2-term clauses. On the other hand, you don't have to check whether things are 0 anymore, because nothing is represented that way.

```
derivedClause :: Clause -> Clause -> Clause
derivedClause l@(Unit _) r@(Disjunction _ _) = derivedClause r l
derivedClause (Disjunction x y) (Unit u)
  | x == u' = Unit y
  | y == u' = Unit x
  where u' = negateLit u
derivedClause (Disjunction x y) (Disjunction p q) 
  | x == p' = clause y q
  | x == q' = clause y p
  | y == p' = clause x q
  | y == q' = clause x p
  where p' = negateLit p
        q' = negateLit q
derivedClause _ _ = Tautology
```

I agree with your (1) as well: `derivedClause` should really return a `Maybe Clause`, rather than returning a Clause that may or may not be useful. But you don't have to rewrite your whole program for this: just the direct clients of `derivedClause`.

As for (3) and your title, I don't see any compelling reason use any monadic machinery here. There's nothing terribly stateful going on: you just have a function from Formula to Formula that you iterate on until you're happy with the result.

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much for such detailed input. This makes a lot of sense. I think I get the idea behind pattern matching a bit better now.